# I have some error in the typescript and the hook of the useParam

Tags: reactjs, typescript

useParam returns string | undefined, but the function requires a string | MutationSelection.
I have error `An argument of type "string | undefined" cannot be assigned to a parameter of type "string | MutationSelection". The type "undefined" cannot be assigned to the type "string | MutationSelection".ts(2345)`.

here is my code

```
const PinDetail: React.FC<PropsType> = ({ user }) => {

  const { pinId } = useParams()

  const addComment = () => {
      client.patch(pinId) //here error
        .setIfMissing({ comments: [] })
        .insert('after', 'comments[-1]', [{
          comment,
          _key: uuidv4(),
          postedBy: {
            _type: 'postedBy',
            _ref: user._id
          }
        }])
        .commit()
        .then(() => {
          fetchPinDetail(), // and here
            setComment('')
          setAddingComment(false)
        })
    }
  }
```

client is object from sanity.io

Comment: `client` can possibly be undefined here. Try `client?.patch(pinId)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to check `pinId` is not undefined before call `client.patch`

Answer (score 0):

I see two way of fixing this:

1. Simply add an `if` condition in `addComment` function

```js
const addComment = () => {
  if (pinId) {
    client
      .patch(pinId)
      .setIfMissing({ comments: [] })
      .insert('after', 'comments[-1]', [
        {
          comment,
          _key: uuidv4(),
          postedBy: {
            _type: 'postedBy',
            _ref: user._id,
          },
        },
      ])
      .commit()
      .then(() => {
        // line ended by , instead of ;
        fetchPinDetail();
        setComment('');
        setAddingComment(false);
      });
  }
};
```

2. Or handle this outside `addComment`

```js
const { pinId } = useParams();

if (!pinId) {
  throw new Error('Unexpected undefined pin id');
}
```

Here I've thrown and error to ensure that `pinId` will be defined in `addComment` but you can handle this differently. For instance you could redirect user to another route or return an error message in JSX.

Comment: Oh i get new error   `Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  @typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions`

Comment: may be it bug of typescript

Comment: I think it's because the `then(() => {})` function was not properly formatted, I'll edit my answer with proper formatting but I'm not sure it'll fix your problem.

Comment: Now it should be better